# IPv4 total length exceeds packet length - always 8.0.69.0

Tags: wireshark, packet

I have a problem... we are capturing packets off the wire in our network but are getting a lot of "IPv4 total length exceeds packet length" errors and always from, 8.0.69.0.
This IP is spurious and the destination seems to be 0.x, 5.x or 1.x, i.e. not valid either.
Some Googling seems to suggest that others have also seen 8.0.69.0 when working with GRE/NAT scenarios. Does anyone have any idea at all what this might be please?

PCAP uploaded [here](https://www.pcapr.net/view/mark/2019/8/4/5/exceed-length.pcap.html).

Answer (score 3):

### Error is Accurate

The error "IPv4 total length exceeds packet length" means exactly what it says: The number of bytes in the IPv4 packet exceeds the number of bytes recorded for the entire frame.

#### Looking at Fields

We can specify both fields of frame length (frame.len, frame.cap_len) and IP length (ip.len) to see this in more depth:

```sh
$ tshark -r exceed-length.pcap -T fields -e frame.len -e frame.cap_len -e ip.len
1478    1478    3114
1536    1536    3114
1476    1476    13615
1399    1399    13781
1478    1478    3114
228     228     13615
195     195     13615
1478    1478    3114
1476    1476    13615
1478    1478    3114
265     265     3114
505     505     3114
1478    1478    3114
88      88      33514
1478    1478    3114
1478    1478    3114
1478    1478    3114
```

As we can see, *each and every* frame has a frame length exceeded by packet length, sometimes by an order of magnitude.

#### What Causes This?

When a capturing program saves a packet in the `pcap` format (as this file is), it prepends each packet with the length the frame that it captured (`frame.cap_len`), the actual frame length (`frame.len`) and capture), and the timestamp. In most cases `frame.cap_len` and `frame.len`, won't differ at all, and they don't here either.

#### How to Fix?

If you want to manually [edit the hex](https://tshark.dev/edit/editing_hex/) of the packet length, it's possible to make this error go away.

### Next Steps

More likely than not, "IPv4 total length exceeds packet length" is incidental to your actual problem. Just because you see an Expert Infos in Wireshark, that does not necessarily mean that it's relevant. You should continue troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

THere's an extra weird header in the packet, [as per the answers when you asked this on the Wireshark Q&A site](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/11712/ipv4-total-length-exceeds-packet-length-always-80690/).

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be extra layers of encapsulation.
Removing the leading 22 bytes was the answer and revealed the correctly formed packets inside. Many thanks